# Start function / Stop function after hover // Javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’am working at this for too much time, please help me..

I want to use this plugin on the my web https://github.com/hmongouachon/mgGlitch
It will be starting after hover on element and it’s fine, I know how to run function for e.g

```
function start() {
    $(".glitch").mgGlitch({
        glitch1TimeMin : 300,
        glitch1TimeMax : 400,
        glitch2TimeMin : 10,
        glitch2TimeMax : 115
    }); 
}


$("#btn-1").hover(
    function() {
      start()
    },
    function() {
       // BUT FOR GOD’S SAKE HOW TO STOP THE GLITCH AND RUN IT AGAIN AFTER 
       // HOVER
    }
);
```

Please good people help me

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
function start() {
  $(".glitch").mgGlitch({
    glitch1TimeMin: 300,
    glitch1TimeMax: 400,
    glitch2TimeMin: 10,
    glitch2TimeMax: 115
  });
}

function stop() {
  $(".glitch").mgGlitch({
    destroy: true
  });
}

$("#btn-1").hover(
  function() {
    start();
  },
  function() {
    stop(); // Based on the docs, this should stop the plugin
  }
);
```

Taken from the documentation [here](https://github.com/hmongouachon/mgGlitch/blob/master/demo/glitch-demo1.html).

Comment: yep its stopping but I cant run it again after hover, It seems to be my main problem right now. Have you any idea how to reset or refresh this plugin ?

Comment: @llucaso, can you throw a working jsfiddle.net together so we can test it?